# I Need Ccavenue Redirect url ,Success url , RSAKey url and cancel url for android api

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, ccavenue

we are developing the android app, we need ccavenue "redirect url, success url, RSAKey and Cancel url ? i searching to online but no one documentation on there please to help me?

Comment: "...i searching to online but no one documentation on there..." Start [here](https://world.ccavenue.com/downloads/CCAVenueWorldIntegrationManual.pdf) with reading documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Download kits from [here](https://login.ccavenue.com/resources/integrationKit.do?command=navigateMobileIntegrationKit&rndTkn=f34027a1e837900393e4109a279c20d4b1213493c9c78b7323d32486c662fe0e#download_rsa_and_response_handling_doc). Download php and android kit. With the PHP kit you will get some important files which you need to place on your server. And later give complete address of where you placed that files. You will get a GetRSA.php file you need to mention path of that file in RSA key URL. And the success, cancel & redirect are all your URLs where you decide what you need to do after getting the response from the CCAvenue. You will get responses from the CCAvenue which you need to catch in those files. Check [this](http://www.bookhungama.com/pdfs/1442054378_CCAvenueIntegration-Ver2.4.pdf) out for their response parameters

Comment: Did you solve the issue, let us know how to do that?